# Scroll to specific position of scrollable object using GWT/Java/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gwt

I have specific page with a couple of CellTables on it.

They are very big and I have a problem with trackpad horizontal scrolling on them (looks like, it's absent on GWT). 
That's why I choose to use scroll handler for them:

```
MouseWheelHandler handler = new MouseWheelHandler() {

      @Override
      public void onMouseWheel(MouseWheelEvent event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            int velocityX = 0;
            int velocityY = 0;
            int positionx=0;
            int positiony=0;

            positionx=event.getX();
            positiony=event.getY();
            velocityX = getMouseWheelVelocityX(event.getNativeEvent()) / 10;
            velocityY = getMouseWheelVelocityY(event.getNativeEvent()) / 10;

            positionx=positionx+velocityX;
            positiony=positiony+velocityY;

      }
  };
```

I am getting a velocity of scroll on X and Y axis and a new position of the scroll.
The last thing I need to do is to scroll to specific position (such as positionX) or scroll by a specific amount of pixels (velocityX, for example).
But I can't use javascript `scrollBy` or `scrollTo` because they are applied to the whole window, not for a specific object (my CellTables).

How to scroll to specific pixel position of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Put your CellTable widget inside a ScrollPanel. A ScrollPanel has all the methods that you need (like `setHorizontalScrollPosition()`, etc.)
2. Use a DataGrid widget instead of a CellTable. A DataGrid widget has a fixed header and footer (if necessary) and a scrollable content inside.

Comment: Well, I've tried that, but have an error while trying to 
                `scrollPanel.setHorizontalScrollPosition(positionx);`
                `scrollPanel.setVerticalScrollPosition(positiony);`
in scrollHandler, because I can't change the scrollPanel positions on it's handler :( How I can change scroll position in ScrollPanel ScrollHandler?

Comment: The reason was, that the scrollPanel was not final. But still need some more investigation with it.